# Copying a material's texture to a render texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have come across copying a normal texture to a render texture using `Graphics.Blit(texture2D, renderTexture);`. But is there a way to copy a skybox texture (360) to a render texture cube? The particular skybox texture fills all the 6 sides with the texture2D. Is there a way to copy all 6 sides to a render texture as well?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, you mean how to convert a material with the `Skybox/6 Sided` shader into a material with the shader `Skybox/Cubemap` which contains a `RenderTexture` of dimension `Cube`?

Comment: Let me explain in detail. The shader skybox converts a panaroma image to a cubemap which fills the entire cube. Can I convert a texture 2D in similar way during runtime to a render texture cube?

Comment: Okay, but passing a `Texture2D` to `RenderTexture Cube` would mean that the image of the `Texture2D` would appear duplicated in each of the 6 sides of the cube, is that what you want?

Comment: @Innat3 Is it possible to divide the texture into each side of the cubemap?

Comment: a single `Texture2D`? no idea. 6 `Texture2D`'s? yes

Comment: So how do I copy 6 texture2Ds to a render texture cubemap?

Comment: [this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/617690/changing-skyboxs-texture-via-code.html) might help